# How to force ECharts charts to a fixed width when printing?

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I'm using some echarts in my Vue application with vue-echarts. All charts have :autoresize="true".

My problem is, that if I try to print the page, the width of the charts are set to match the width of the browser. If browser is full screen then some charts get clipped.

CSS:
    .echarts {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 200px;
    }

```
@media print {
@page { margin: 1cm }
  body {
    width: 110mm;
    height: 297mm;
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;
  }
  .echarts {width: 600px !important;} /* This does not work! */
}
```

In the generated DOM there is a  container, and inside that another div with the style: position: relative; width: 567px; height: 400px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;

Width of the inner container is updated when browser is resized.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have faced the same problem. I have also tried before print and after print and call function to redraw the chart but some times its break when Brower gets a zoom out and zoom in.

I say it's not the best solution but it works perfectly.

Solution -

Overwrite the `window.print` method in `mounted`.

```
window.print = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    _print();
                }, 500);
            };
```

use flag `print_mode` for printing.

```
        let self = this;
        window.addEventListener('afterprint', function () {
            self.print_mode = false;
        });
```

user ref of the chart instance to get `base64` data. call `getDataURL()` to get image data.

```
chart = echarts.init(chart_dom);

chart_img = chart.getDataURL()


<img v-if="print_mode" class="print-only" :src="chart_img"></img>
```

so while printing it display image and print and in normal mode, it shows a chart.

Comment: If you have any other solution please share.

Comment: Thanks, finally I had the time to test it out! I added a button to render printable page, created the echarts off screen and then used getDataUrl.

I'm still thinking if, instead of using getDataUL() and bitmaps, it would be possible to utilize svg versions of the charts. In order to get decent looking charts, I need to generate them in 200% scale.